# Python link sublists together that sublists have no element in list2 and have a element in list3

Tags: python, list

I need to group sublists with the same elements together and all element in sublists have no element in `list2` and have a element in `list3`
For example:

```
list1 = [[1,4],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[9,7],[10,9],[8,10],[8,11],[8,13],[13,15]]
list2 = [7,8]
list3 = [1,6,11,13]
```

I would link `[4,5]` and `[1,4]` together since they both contain 1 same number and those two would combine into `[1,4,5]` and they contain `1` in `list3` and not contain `7` in `list2`

So after linking, the new list should be like:

```
new_list1 = [[1,4,5],[6],[11],[13,15]]
```

IE: there shouldn't be same number inside a sub-list and order is not important.

A longer example:

```
list1 = [[1,4],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[9,7],[10,9],[8,10],[8,11],[8,13],[6,8],[20,2],[20,3],[11,14],[14,16],[13,15]]
list2 = [7,8,20]
list3 = [1,2,3,16,15]
```

after linking, it would be

```
new_list = [[1,4,5],[2,3],[11,14,16],[13,15]]
```

How can this be done in a general way?

**EDIT**
The final algorithm should comprise of the following three basic steps:

1. Remove all elements of all sub-lists of `list1` that are contained in `list2`
2. Join all sub-lists of `list1` that have common elements
3. Remove all sub-lists of `list1` that do not contain any elements of `list3`

Comment: It is not clear to me which lists you are linking in order to get the desired result. In your first example, where does the `[1,4]` come from?

Comment: Sorry i fixed it, its in list1

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Ok, so basically there should be two steps: first go through `list1` and join all lists that have common elements, eliminating doubles; second keep only lists that contain elements in 'list3', but delete elements that are in `list2`. Am I right?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Yes exactly

Comment: this can be easily done with sets. I let you look the official documentation. Juste put the inners list into a set.

Comment: The order is important here. If I do things the way I outlined, the sub-lists `[8,13]` and `[13,15]` are joined together, after which the desired output cannot be obtained. Could you please update the question to outline the exact algorithm you are after. Also, post anything you have tried already.

Comment: 8 will be not added with 13 and 15 because its in list2, any number in list2 will not be added to the output

Comment: @jack - your desired algorithm is definitely unclear. For example, how do you determine how to 'link' your sublists? Given `list1 = [[1,4],[4,5],[5,7]]` how did you determine to link `[1,4]` and `[4,5]` (because they contain a common element - `4`) to form `[1,4,5]` but not `[4,5]` and `[5,7]` since they also contain a common element - `5`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222469/python-about-linking-sublist-with-same-number-together/44222747?noredirect=1#comment75457497_44222747

Comment: but the above link is without using list2 to remove numbers

Comment: @zwer my original interpretation was wrong. The algorithm goes as follows: 1. go through all sub-lists of `list1` and remove all elements that can be found in `list2`. 2. join all sub-lists of `list1` that have common elements. 3. remove all sub-lists that do not contain any number from `list3`. I will edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on it, if Thomas Kühn managed to properly read your mind:

```
def subgroup_join(data, exclude, include):
    exclude = set(exclude)  # turn into set for faster lookup/compare
    include = set(include)  # turn into set for faster lookup/compare
    data = [set(element) - exclude for element in data]  # remove excluded elements
    results = [set()]  # init with an empty set
    for element in data:  # loop through our remaining elements
        groups = []  # store elements / current results filtered by exclude list
        ignore_element = False  # flag if we should add the element as a standalone
        for result in results:  # go through each subgroup in the results
            if element & result:  # if the current element has common items with the result
                result |= element  # ... concatenate both into a subgroup
                ignore_element = True
            groups.append(result)  # add the current result subgroup
        if not ignore_element:  # add only if the element wasn't concatenated
            groups.append(element)  # add the current element
        results = groups  # our element store becomes our new results set
    return sorted([sorted(res) for res in results if result & include])  # sort & return
```

As for tests:

```
list1 = [[1, 4], [4, 5], [5, 7], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 7], [10, 9], [8, 10], [8, 11], [8, 13], [13, 15]]
list2 = [7, 8]
list3 = [1, 6, 11, 13]

print(subgroup_join(list1, list2, list3))
# prints: [[1, 4, 5], [6], [11], [13, 15]]

list1 = [[1, 4], [4, 5], [5, 7], [6, 7], [9, 7], [10, 9], [8, 10], [8, 11], [8, 13], [6, 8], [20, 2], [20, 3], [11, 14], [14, 16], [13, 15]]
list2 = [7, 8, 20]
list3 = [1, 2, 3, 16, 15]

print(subgroup_join(list1, list2, list3))
# prints: [[1, 4, 5], [2], [3], [11, 14, 16], [13, 15]]
```

This is probably the fastest approach from the presented, but again - it doesn't exactly match your examples - check the last result set and the `[2]` and `[3]` results.

**UPDATE**:

When it comes to performance, using the second list group:

```
zwer_join - 100,000 loops: 2.849 s; per loop: 28.399 µs
kuhn_join - 100,000 loops: 3.071 s; per loop: 30.706 µs
nuag_join -   1,000 loops: 15.82 s; per loop: 15.819 ms (had to reduce the number of loops)
```

Comment: Very well structured. You definitely have more practice with sets than I do :)

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the job:

```
list1 = [[1,4],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[9,7],[10,9],[8,10],[8,11],[8,13],[6,8],[20,2],[20,3],[11,14],[14,16],[13,15]]
list2 = [7,8,20]
list3 = [1,2,3,16,15]

list1a = [set(l) for l in list1]
#removing elements from list1 that contain numbers of list2:
for x in list2:
    for l in list(list1a):
        if x in l:
            l.remove(x)

#joining sub-lists in list1:
list1b = [set(l) for l in list1a]
list1c = []
while list1b:
    s1 = list1b.pop(0)
    for s2 in list(list1b):
        if s1 & s2:
            s1 |= s2
            list1b.remove(s2)
    list1c.append(s1)

#generating final list with only sub-lists that contain elements of list2
list1_new = sorted([sorted(list(s)) for s in list1c if s & set(list3)])
```

For the first example, this gives:

```
[[1, 4, 5], [6], [11], [13, 15]]
```

and for the second example

```
[[1, 4, 5], [2], [3], [11, 14, 16], [13, 15]]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second result set doesn't produce a singular `[2,3]` as OP showed in his examples.

Comment: @zwer I know. It cannot work, because `20` is in the 'forbidden list', thus `[20,2]` and `[20,3]` cannot be joined. It must be a mistake by the asker.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I know the reason why it doesn't produce the right result but there either is something more to the algorithm or there is a mistake in the question and at this point one cannot be sure taking into the account the OP's ability to explain his problem.

Comment: @zwer so how should one deal with such situations? Flag as unclear? Edit the question? Do nothing? Apparently he's happy with the result of the other answer, which is identical to mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you start by writing your `join` function. I included the second list to remove unwanted elements.

Then you iterate through your joined list and look if any of the elements are currently in your list. If yes, you look for the place where they belongs, then you add elements (I used `set` to avoid duplicate).

Outputs are given at the end.

```
def join(list1, list2):
    l = []
    for ee in list1:
        # We consider here that list1 only have pairs
        if ee[0] not in list2 and ee[1] not in list2:
            flat_l = [x for e in l for x in e]
            if ee[0] in flat_l or ee[1] in flat_l:
                for i, e in enumerate(l):
                    if ee[0] in e:
                        l[i].append(ee[1])
                    if ee[1] in e:
                        l[i].append(ee[0])
            else:
                l.append(ee)
    return l

def f(list1,list2,list3):
    l = [[e] for e in list3]
    list1 = join(list1, list2)
    for ee in list1:
        flat_l = [x for e in l for x in e]
        for e in ee:
            if e in flat_l:
                for i in range(len(l)):
                    if e in l[i]:
                        l[i] = list(set(l[i]+ee))
    print(l)

list1 = [[1,4],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[9,7],[10,9],[8,10],[8,11],[8,13],[13,15]]
list2 = [7,8]
list3 = [1,6,11,13]

f(list1,list2,list3)
# [[1, 4, 5], [6], [11], [13, 15]]

list1 = [[1,4],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[9,7],[10,9],[8,10],[8,11],[8,13],[6,8],[20,2],[20,3],[11,14],[14,16],[13,15]]
list2 = [7,8,20]
list3 = [1,2,3,16,15]

f(list1,list2,list3)
# [[1, 4, 5], [2], [3], [16, 11, 14], [13, 15]]
```

Comment: is it possible to make it faster?

Comment: Probably, depends on the effort and time you are ready to make. Still you'll be dependant on `append()` which is slow.